# Getting FIN ACK message just after doing 220 start TLS negotiation

Tags: starttls

I am getting FIN ACK once the server is doing Response code:  Service ready (220) for TLS connection.

[Packet capture 1](http://dropcanvas.com/sxypg/1), [Packet capture 2](http://dropcanvas.com/sxypg/2)

I am not sure about the reason why my server is FIN the TLS connection as it supports TLS connection.

Comment: Unfortunately SO doesn't support the image link (might be because it's missing an extension). If you provide another URL, I'll add the image to the question.

Comment: I tried to link the images into your post, but the service you used doesn't support HTTPS, and Stack Overflow accepts only links to images using HTTPS. Please use https://imgur.com/ to upload your images. Thanks!